# How to make objects not scroll with page html+css

Tags: html, css

Currently my dropdown menu ive created does not appear under the button it is clicked from. It hovers freely and moves with the page if you scroll down. I need it to be fixed in place.

I tried changing position: fixed; to position: relative; but for some reason that breaks the code and the dropdown menus don't appear anymore when buttons clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">
//this shows the first two buttons for example
<ul class="matchup">
            <li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
</body>


<script> //opens dropdown menu when button clicked
    document.querySelectorAll("li.team").forEach(function(teamDom) {
      teamDom.querySelector("button.drop-down-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        teamDom.querySelector("div.dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
      });
    });
  </script>

<style>
.btn {
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    color: black;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
  }

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btn:hover,
  .btn:focus {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }



  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .show {
    display: block;
  }

  .open-button {
    display: show;
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #5391CC;
    z-index: 1;
  }

</style>
```

Actual output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMqM2.jpg

Expected output is for the dropdown menu to drop down below the selected button, and wont scroll with page

Answer (score 1):

**Just omit 'position: fixed' from class '.open-button'**

As the title i do it in the attachment code.

Also I move the 'margin-bottom: 10px;' to the 'li' tag from the 'button' tag.
So now the menu does appear under the button.

Hope I helped a bit.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li.team").forEach(function(teamDom) {
      teamDom.querySelector("button.drop-down-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        teamDom.querySelector("div.dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
      });
    });
```

```css
li{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    color: black;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
    opacity: 1;
  }

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .btn:hover,
  .btn:focus {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }



  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .show {
    display: block;
  }

  .open-button {
    display: show;
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 10px 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
/*     position: fixed; */
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #5391CC;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="matchup">
            <li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
<li class="team team-top">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">01</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button teamName" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamWinner" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button teamScore" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="team team-bottom">
              <button class="btn drop-down-btn">
                <span class="seed">32</span>
                <span id="team1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="score">&nbsp;</span>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
                <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Moving it to the 'li' tag helped it appear under the button correctly, thank you for that. But getting rid of position: fixed again for some reason makes the menu not appear when clicked anymore. (maybe it somehow appears off the screen? I have no idea why it breaks the code)

Answer (score 0):

Make `.team` class `position: relative`. This way, all it's children that is absolute positioned, is relative to this element.

Absolute positioned elements will always be relative to the closest parent that has a position of relative. If there is none, it will default to the boundaries of your browser.

This means that if you have a absolute positioned element with the following style:

```
.absolute-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

It will be displayed at the very top of the web-page.

However, if the parent of this element(`.absolute-element`) has this class:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

The `.absolute-element` will be displayed at the top of the `.parent` element box, not the top of the browser.

In your case, the dropdown will be at the top of each `.team` elements.